# calculate distance between two location by enter latitude and longitude from EditText

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm trying to calculate distance between two locations on Google map. I'm inputting latitude and longitude from `EditText`, 
but the return value is zero meters. What goes wrong in the code, i.e., how to get the real distance?

Here is a picture of my app:

[image]

```
public class Ma`inActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
private TextView source;
private TextView destination;
private EditText sLatitude1;
private EditText sLongtiude1;
private EditText dLatitude2;
private EditText dLongtiude2;
private Button button;

private GoogleMap mMap;
boolean mapReady = false;
MarkerOptions elsedaway;
MarkerOptions Elrob3;
Location location;



 static final CameraPosition elfayoum = CameraPosition.builder()
        .target(new LatLng(29.309324, 30.842973))
        .zoom(1)
        .bearing(6)
        .tilt(45)
        .build();
double lati1;
double longi1;
double lati2;
double longi2;
TextView textView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // find text that display distance
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.distance);
    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    // find edit text and text view
    source = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sourc);
    destination = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.destination);
    sLatitude1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lat1);
    sLongtiude1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.long1);
    dLatitude2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lat2);
    dLongtiude2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.long2);
    // find button
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getDistance);
    // find string from edittext
    String lat1 = sLatitude1.getText().toString();
    // parse string to double
    lati1 = ParseDouble(lat1);
    String lon1 = sLongtiude1.getText().toString();
    longi1 = ParseDouble(lon1);
    String lat2 = dLatitude2.getText().toString();
    lati2 = ParseDouble(lat2);
    String lon2 = dLongtiude2.getText().toString();
    longi2 = ParseDouble(lon2);
    Log.i("**lat", lat2);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            double xy1 = distanceBetween(new LatLng(lati1, longi1), new LatLng(lati1, longi2));
            String distanceis = fmt(xy1) + "meter";
            textView.setText(distanceis);
        }

    });


}

// mehtod to parse double from string

double ParseDouble(String strNumber) {
    if (strNumber != null && strNumber.length() > 0) {
        try {
            return Double.parseDouble(strNumber);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return -1;   // or some value to mark this field is wrong. or make a function validates field first ...
        }
    } else return 0;
}

// get distance
public static Double distanceBetween(LatLng point1, LatLng point2) {
    if (point1 == null || point2 == null) {
        return null;
    }
    double vw = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(point1, point2);
    Log.i("distance isby utillib ", String.valueOf(vw));
    return vw;
}

public String fmt(double d) {

    return String.format("%s", d);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mapReady = true;
    mMap = googleMap;
    //    if(elsedaway!=null){
    //    mMap.addMarker(elsedaway);};
   //      mMap.addMarker(Elrob3);

 mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().geodesic(true)
                    .add(new LatLng(lati1, longi1))
                    .add(new LatLng(lati2, lati2))
            mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                    .center(new LatLng(29.291540, 30.601884))
                    .radius(500044)
                    .strokeColor(Color.GREEN)
                    .fillColor(Color.argb(54, 99, 255, 0)));
    flyTo(elfayoum);
}
```

Comment: have a look on 2 method : distanceBetween and distanceTo on https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move this punch of code into your onCLick, and Correct your values, your code should be like :

```
  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
    String lat1 = sLatitude1.getText().toString();
    // parse string to double
    lati1 = ParseDouble(lat1);
    String lon1 = sLongtiude1.getText().toString();
    longi1 = ParseDouble(lon1);
    String lat2 = dLatitude2.getText().toString();
    lati2 = ParseDouble(lat2);
    String lon2 = dLongtiude2.getText().toString();
    longi2 = ParseDouble(lon2);
            double xy1 = distanceBetween(new LatLng(lati1, longi1), new LatLng(lati2, longi2));
            String distanceis = fmt(xy1) + "meter";
            textView.setText(distanceis);
        }

    });
```

Comment: thanks it done  -- another question -- i need to add Marker Option to the position that i get it 
and this my code  but  app crash 
----------------------------------------------------------
elsedaway= new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lati1,longi1))
                        .title("place").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bubble_mask));
i put  it on onClick 
can give me some help

Comment: @mohammedragabmohammedborik it's better to ask new question with new issue, you can mention me with it, and please if my answer helped you as well you can accept it :)

Comment: i accept your answer  :(

 
thanks it done -- another question -- i need to add Marker Option to the position that i get it and this my code but app crash ---------------------------------------------------------- elsedaway= new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lati1,longi1)) .title("place").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.‌​drawable.bubble_mask‌​)); i put it on onClick can give me some help

Comment: i mention  to you but mention not appear i do not why ?

Comment: i have less than  15 REPUTATION  .

Comment: @mohammedragabmohammedborik you accept answer by click on the check mark under the vote system, also you can put your new link for your quesyion here.

Comment: where i put my new question ? can you help me ? need answer

Comment: @mohammedragabmohammedborik the same way you asked this question!

Comment: i do not know where  can you give me a picture for detail  where i can put question??

Answer (score 3):

This [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) might help you to find the distance between 2 lat long points.

[Here](https://bigdatanerd.wordpress.com/2011/11/03/java-implementation-of-haversine-formula-for-distance-calculation-between-two-points/) is java implementation of haversine formula.

Hope this may help

Answer (score 1):

For starters, there is a mistake here :

```
double xy1 = distanceBetween(new LatLng(lati1, longi1), new LatLng(lati1, longi2));
```

You should be using `lati2` instead of `lati1` in your second argument.

And also, move the `getText()` inside the `onClick(...)` block.

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v)
          {
              // find string from edittext
              String lat1 = sLatitude1.getText().toString();
              // parse string to double
              lati1 = ParseDouble(lat1);
              String lon1 = sLongtiude1.getText().toString();
              longi1 = ParseDouble(lon1);
              String lat2 = dLatitude2.getText().toString();
              lati2 = ParseDouble(lat2);
              String lon2 = dLongtiude2.getText().toString();
              longi2 = ParseDouble(lon2);

              ...
          }
      });
```

Comment: i change it give me same distance remain  distance Zero

Comment: Also move the `getText()` in your `onClick`. See my edit.

Comment: thanks it done  -- another question -- i need to add Marker Option to the position that i get it 
and this my code  but  app crash 
----------------------------------------------------------
elsedaway= new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lati1,longi1))
                        .title("place").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bubble_mask));
i put  it on onClick 
can give me some help